# Le verbe pour décrire l'arrivée des vagues sur la côte

Tags: vocabulaire

Je cherche le verbe qui sert à exprimer l'arrivée des vagues sur la côte. Peut-on utiliser les verbes frapper ou se briser ?

[image: Les vagues]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dans l’image soumise, avant leur arrivée au rivage, lorsqu’elles atteignent les moindres profondeurs, les vagues **déferlent**, c'est-à-dire qu'elles se brisent et commencent à écumer.

L’écrivain Saint-Exupéry a parlé de *l’épanchement des vagues*, on pourra donc aussi dire, pour l’avancée, que les vagues **s’épanchent**. Ce cas décrira un mouvement doux et peu violent, comme dans l'image.

Pour une arrivée plus brutale, on pourra dire que les vagues **frappent** la côte.

Sur un haut fond localisé, entouré de mer *(et donc techniquement pas un rivage)*, les vagues **se briseront**.

Comment: 15 seconds late ;-)

Comment: What can I say! You got me!

Comment: To be fair, you certainly started typing before I did. A StackExchange enhancement might be some kind of indication when someone starts to write an answer like the feedback we have with instant messaging (xxx is typing).

Answer (score 2):

**Déferler, se briser, frapper, se fracasser** sont possibles avec des nuances pour l'intensité.

Comment: merci de votre aide !

Answer (score 1):

Un peu différemment, le [*roulement*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/roulement) peut désigner par analogie le *mouvement d'un liquide*, et le verbe [*rouler*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rouler) peut avoir trait au *mouvement tournoyant* de l'eau et à ses conséquences, ou s'intéresser par analogie à un *élément fluide*, comme au comportement des nuages et les vagues nous dit-on (TLFi). Et donc c'est indirectement relié, peut-être plus au nom qu'au verbe, et ce n'est pas toujours « sur la côte » comme telle mais ça pourrait être utile dans certains contextes :

> -Qu'elle est sinistre, la mer qui roule dans ce golfe ses lames vertes
>   et brouillées! (Bourget)
>  -La campagne silencieuse Roulait ses
>   vagues de blé mûr. (Lorrain)
>  -Les sables sont des débris de
>   marnes, de roches, de coquillages, de cailloux ou galets, que l'océan
>   réduit sans cesse en poudre par le roulement perpétuel de ses flots au
>   fond de son bassin, et surtout sur ses rivages. (Bern. de St-P.)
>   -Le roulement des hautes lames [de l'Adriatique], si différent des
>   gestes que la tempête méditerranéenne fait sur les rochers.
>   (Giono)
>
> [Citations tirées du *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* (TLFi), à *roulement* et
>   *rouler* ]

Answer (score 1):

Si on veut être plus imagé, on peut utiliser **mourir** ou **s’échouer**:

> Les vagues meurent sur la plage.
>
> Les vagues s’échouent sur le rivage.